# Can I use old Masquerade supplemental material in Vampire: the Requiem?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-requiem, the-camarilla-minds-eye-society, minds-eye-theatre

So I just started a nWoD Requiem game with the Mind's Eye Society and know nothing about what books can and cannot be used.

I found a few things that I like in the Masquerade Gangrel handbook. There were things about Gangrels being able to have deformities that helped them and had flaws as well. Like there was one where you have a bigger more elongated kind of bulky mouth, that is filled with all fang-like teeth. This gives the Gangrel an aggravated bite. There was also something on wings as well; they could not support flight, but did give a person advantages in small situations. Does anyone know if these things are used in the new Requiem game, or even if that book is useable at all in the Requiem game?

Comment: The list of what books can and cannot be used is available in the Universal and Requiem Addenda. You can find the new Addenda on this page: http://www.mindseyesociety.org/information/next-chronicle-addendums/

Comment: @Jadasc that looks like the best answer to me!

Comment: These questions have prompted [a Meta discussion about how we tag WoD questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2880/shall-we-review-the-various-world-of-darkness-tags-use). Regular users interested in tagging issues, please chime in!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Any content not written specifically for the new game is not useable in the new game.**

Totally leaving aside White Wolf's desire to sell you new/more books, the different vampire types don't work the same way in Requiem as they did in Masquerade, and a lot of clans disappeared entirely.

If you want to find options for a Gangrel character, I would recommend the new Gangrel clan book, [*Gangrel: Savage and Macabre*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1588463532).

Answer (score 5):

As an answer to your particular circumstance, the list of what books can and cannot be used in the MES ([Modern Enigma Society](https://www.modernenigmasociety.org/) since 2021, formerly the Mind's Eye Society, formerly the Camarilla Fan Club) live-action chronicle was available in the Universal and Requiem Addenda. You once could find the new Addenda [on this page](http://www.mindseyesociety.org/games/next-chronicle-genres/), but the page died without leaving a trace.

Comment: The page died sadly - and the last cached version of 2021 is already 404: https://web.archive.org/web/20210126060841/http://www.mindseyesociety.org/games/next-chronicle-genres/

Comment: buuuuut, they changed their name to modern enigma Society about 3 years ago. https://www.modernenigmasociety.org/

Comment: @Trish They also don't have a Requiem chronicle going anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the Mind Eye Society would allow such house rule.

If you were playing a regular game, technically, you could pick the merits the Storyteller allows you. So, if you come up with an explanation of why your character have those traits, he could allow them. In this concrete case it's difficult because they are based on the Masquerade Gangrel weaknesses. But still, if your Storyteller find it cool, or at least reasonable, he could grant you those mutation abilities, or even change your weakness.

Or you could belong to a bloodline with that weakness or power.

As a response, to the more general question of the title, there is a [guide to use Masquerade material in Requiem and viceversa](http://feuros.com/WoD/VtR/Vampire%20Translation%20Guide.pdf). This material is optional, and I don't think any LARP club is actually using it, but traditional roleplaying groups could if it pleased them. Let's see what it says about gangrels:

> Of the three clans that appear in both Masquerade and Requiem as full
>   clans, the Gangrel are probably the one that changed the least. Both
>   versions of the Gangrel are animalistic and self-reliant. Masquer- ade
>   Gangrel focus a bit more on the wilderness and dwelling between
>   cities, while their Requiem coun- terparts are simply predatory,
>   rather than strictly animalistic. Requiem Gangrel are also a bit more
>   willing to join sects and spend time around other Kindred, but beyond
>   that, a Gangrel character can be shifted between the two games fairly
>   easily.
>
> Requiem Gangrel: The Gangrel are already a core clan of Vampire: The
>   Requiem.
>
> Systems: The system that needs to switch over from Masquerade’s
>   portrayal of Clan Gangrel is the weakness. Every time a Gangrel
>   succumbs to frenzy, she gains an animalistic feature, such as slitted
>   eyes, tufted ears, wolf-like hair, and so on. While the system
>   presented in Masquerade for these features (for every five, the
>   character loses a dot of a Social Attribute) can be ported to Requiem,
>   it seems a bit harsh. An alternative might be that every three such
>   features imposes a –1 penalty to Manipulation or Presence rolls,
>   except those made to Intimidate.
>
> The favored Attributes of the Gangrel remain Composure and Stamina.

Comment: The problem with your solution in the first paragraph is that merits work quite differently in Masquerade than they do in Requiem. The storyteller would need to come up with a custom background dot cost, and as a member of a sanctioned LARP chronicle, he's not empowered to do that.

Comment: I think you must also take into account that coming up all those custom things would not work, considering for those type of things i would most likely have to go high or to the top just to get that approval as well. That is never something easy to just get done and over with. So using old merits and think would probably be declined by anyone higher then a mid level approval, who knows if it would even make it that far.

Comment: @Jadasc But this answer will be useful to those not in a MES, and it's better to answer the specific and then the general, since Google will bring every sort of asker to thus question. And it's better than having another question where sanctioned/not is the only only difference.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Honestly, I missed the MES part, and thought it was a regular tabletop game with friends. Anyway, I see your point and I hope the answer helps somebody. Also, I felt compelled to answer the question of the title, which is quite different to the one on the body. The title is what people looking for answers will see.

Comment: @Flamma Not your fault—I had edited "MES" out while cleaning it up, not realising it was important to the question. Still, the general answer is useful. If you edited the answer a bit to say something like "well you can't in a MES, but more generally here's how it would work", then it would be a perfectly good answer to this question, *and* helpful to others playing home games.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Ok, done. I hope I haven't messed up with verbal tenses :S